# Number of distinct limits of subsequences of a sequence is finite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

"The number of distinct limits of subsequences of a sequence is finite?"

I've been mulling over this question for a while, and I think it is true, but I can't see how I might prove this formally. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Enumerate the rationals as $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots$. Every  real number is the limit of a subsequence of $(r_n)$.

Comment: What's nice about this example is that not only the number of limits is infinite, it's strictly larger than the size of the sequence! :-)

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

No, the following is a counter-example: Let $E: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N^2$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb N^2$, and set $a_n = (E(n))_1$. Then $a_n$ contains a constant sub-sequence $a_{n_i} = k$ for every $k \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.
Think for instance about subsequences of $(cos(n))$: after showing that the integers are dense in $[0,2\pi]$, it follows that for every real number $k$ in $[-1,1]$ there exists a subsequence $(cos(n_k))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $k$. In particular, not only the number of distinct limits of subsequences is infinite, but uncountably infinite.